# Unable to read and get data from generic pass created using google wallet API on any nfc reader

Tags: java, php, android

Im able to create a generic pass in the google wallet with the mentioned properties: enableSmartTap as well as smartTapRedemptionValue but when I'm trying to read on Hik Visions Terminal Model: DS-K1T671MF using nfc it's reading some data but every time its random card no what it's getting not what i mentioned.

I need to read that custom generic pass in google wallet on any nfc based reader for access and get the data from that pass

I created a custom pass using google wallet api with data in payload as well as smartTap enabled and data in "smartTapRedemptionValue" and when i tried to scan on any mobile nfc reader application or  in HIK Vision's DS-K1T671MF facial Recognition Terminal using NFC it's detecting card but always print any random value in card no and m unable to fetch data from that google wallet pass using any nfc reader.